# if then else in Regex in DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to rationalize a quite scrambled phonebook xls of several thousandth of records. Some fields are kind of merged with other and/or saved into the wrong column, while other filed are splitted through 2 or more ones... and so on. I'm trying to find the path of the main error and solve those through regex, placing the right record into right column.
An example:
DataFrame as df:

| id | Name | SecondName | Surname | Title | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Marc |  | Gigio |  | ETC ltd |
| 02 | Piero (Four | Season | Restaurant |  | ) |
| 03 | bubbu(Caterpilar) |  |  |  |  |
| 04 |  |  |  |  | gaby(ts Inc) |
| 05 | Pit(REV inc) |  |  |  | REV Inc |
| 06 | Pluto |  |  |  |  |

- In record 01: would nothing to do, but see how manage conditional exception as point 5.
- In record 02: merge Name + SecondName + Surname , then extract from new string the name (Piero) to place in Name column while extract from same string the content of squared bracket and place it into Company Column

  df['Nameall_tmp'] = df[Name]+' '+df[SecondName]+' '+df[Surname]+' '+df[Company]
  df['Name_tmp'] = df[Nameall_tmp].str.extract(r'(.+)(.+')
  df['Company_tmp'] = df[Nameall_tmp].str.extract(r'.*((.+))')
- In record 03 and 04: is almost 02
- In record 06:
  df['Nameall_tmp'] = df[Name]+' '+df[SecondName]+' '+df[Surname]+' '+df[Company]
  df['Name_tmp'] = df['Nameall_tmp'].str.extract(r'(.+)(.+')
  df['Name_tmp']= np.where(df['Name_tmp'] == 'nan' , df['Name'],df['Name_tmp'] )

In this case np.where statement doesn't work like if then else, in order to check if df['Name_tmp'] is "nan", in the case, fill with original df['Name'] to eliminate "nan" from record,else take df['Name_tmp']. Any sugestion ?

Comment: didn't know you could have tables renderred in here. learnt something, thank you

Comment: ;-) me either new by almost a spare case !

Comment: Did you solve the problem or do you need more help?

Comment: Eliu's solution it's very powerfull and open to a wide of customized solution ! with that trick I can solve further other situations ...just need to refine his Regex proposal in assignment of rex variable. What I need is to find and study documentation on how Regex can create columns in a dataframe.. that's is totally missing to me.. Thank you, Wiktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough thinking here:

1. munge the "company" column so that: if it contains a legit company name,
   add `()` to it. If not, keep original content
2. concat all columns into one conglomerate column
3. use 1 regex to `sr.str.extract(rex)` that single conglomerate column into desired columns again

anyways, following the rough thinking, I have at least reduced the problem into fine tunning a single regex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns="   index                 Name    SecondName    Surname         Company ".split(),
    data= [
            [       0,              "Marc",       np.nan,   "Gigio",      "ETC ltd", ],
            [       1,             "Piero",      "(four",  "season",  "restaurant)", ],
            [       2, "bubbu(caterpilar)",       np.nan,    np.nan,         np.nan, ],
            [       3,              np.nan,       np.nan,    np.nan, "gaby(ts inc)", ],
            [       4,      "Pit(REV inc)",       np.nan,    np.nan,      "REV inc", ],
            [       5,             "pluto",       np.nan,    np.nan,         np.nan, ],]).set_index("index", drop=True)

df = df.fillna('')

df['Company'] = df['Company'].apply(lambda x: f'({x})' if ('(' not in x and ')' not in x and x!="") else x)
# df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)

df['sum'] = df['Name'] + ' ' + df['SecondName'] + ' ' + df['Surname'] + ' ' + df['Company']
df['sum'] = df['sum'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True) # get rid of extra \s due to above concat

rex = re.compile( # very fragil and hardcoded,
    r"""
    (?P<name0>[a-z]{2,})
    \s?
    (?P<surename0>[a-z]{2,})?
    \s?
    \(? 
    (?P<company0>[a-z\s]{3,})?  
    \)?
    \s?
    """,
    re.X+re.I
)

df['sum'].str.extract(rex)
```

output:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+------------------------+
|   index | name0   | surename0   | company0               |
|---------+---------+-------------+------------------------|
|       0 | Marc    | Gigio       | ETC ltd                |
|       1 | Piero   | nan         | four season restaurant |
|       2 | bubbu   | nan         | caterpilar             |
|       3 | gaby    | nan         | ts inc                 |
|       4 | Pit     | nan         | REV inc                |
|       5 | pluto   | nan         | nan                    |
+---------+---------+-------------+------------------------+
```

EDIT:
Earlier answer contains an error in my regex (forgot to `?` the `\(`), couldn't quite handle "pluto", corrected now.
The moral of the story is that, the regex you need to design will be very very specialized, fragil and hardcoded. almost worth considering a `df['sum'].apply(myfoo)` approach just to parse `df['sum']` more thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks eliu. Since I'm kind of newby in python I need to study your routine in depth. Especially last part of rex assignment:  Its almost work but can not understand clearly (is almost unknown to me) the construction of rex, to eventually try make modifications for a more customized function. You helped me quite a lot, till now. Thanks !!

Comment: if you will be dealing with string in your future endeavours, regex is a huge boost. Also, google `series.str`, most of that are based on regex. Half of using linux involves regex. If you like the answer please accept and upvote.

Comment: I'm reading the help section of regex concerning the grouping and var/label assignment ((?P<var>)): impressive and powerful tool ! thanks again to had me revealed new horizon in programming !!